# Найти утечку памяти

Tags: c

Здравствуйте. Есть функция добавления узла в начало связного списка:

```
int AddToBegin(struct Node** ppSource, struct Node** ppNode) {
    if(*ppSource == NULL || *ppNode == NULL) { return -1; }
    (*ppNode)->Next = *ppSource;
    *ppSource = *ppNode;
    return 0;
}
```

Intel Inspector говорит, что здесь есть утечка памяти, а именно по указателю *ppSource. 
Но я не смог её найти. Помогите пожалуйста.
Функция main:

```
int main() {
    struct Node* pNode, *pTemp;
    pNode=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    pTemp=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    Initialize(&pNode, 0,0);
    Initialize(&pTemp, 1, 1);
    AddToBegin(&pNode, &pTemp);
    ShowList(pNode); //Просто показывает все элементы в списке
    free(pNode);
    return 0;
}

void Initialize(struct Node** ppNode, int x, int y) {
    (*ppNode)->x = x;
    (*ppNode)->y = y;
    (*ppNode)->Next = NULL;
    return;
}
```

Comment: Вы бы описание структуры Node привели, а также код  инициализации и вызова AddToBegin(). 

Навскидку, надо

    (*ppNode)->Next = (*ppSource)->Next;
    (*ppSource)->Next = *ppNode;

Comment: Структура:

    struct Node {
        int x, y;
        struct Node* Next;
    };

Comment: @avp, сделал, как вы сказали - не добавляет

Comment: @avp: Судя по коду, там список без выделенной головы.

Comment: Кстати, поскольку указателю `*ppNode` ничего не присваивается, его можно передавать и по значению.

Comment: Контекста недостаточно, в этом коде ошибок не видно. Разве что, добавьте проверку, что `(*ppNode)->Next == NULL`. И приведите больше кода.

Comment: @VladD, кода добавил

Comment: а почему в main два malloc'а, а free всего один?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Значит так. Код добавления более-менее правильный, а вот что вы не делаете -- это правильное освобождение структуры.

Попробуйте вот такое:

```
void DestroyList(Node** ppList)
{
    Node* pCurr = *ppList;
    while (pCurr)
    {
        Node* pNext = pCurr->Next;
        free(pCurr);
        pCurr = pNext;
    }
    *ppList = NULL;
}
```

Вы же делаете просто `free`, удаляя лишь первый элемент списка.

Answer (score 0):

Попробую угадать. Где-то динамически создаются две структуры -  А (`**ppNode`) и В (`**ppSource`). Получаются два указателя на эти структуры. Далее в приведенную функцию передаются адреса этих указателей. В этой функции происходит следующее. Полю `Next` структуры А присваивается значение адреса структуры В. После этого указателю на структуру В присваивается значение адреса структуры А. В результате теряется адрес структуры В. Память, где находится структура В, утекает.

Comment: Вы уверены? Ведь адрес структуры `B` теперь доступен как `A.Next`.

Answer (score 0):

```
pNode=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
pTemp=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

free(pNode);
а где  free(pTeml); ???
```

Comment: когда делаю

    free(temp)

появляется ошибка какая-то